# urlrewrite images to codeigniter controller method gives page not found error

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, codeigniter-3

I've a codeigniter site up and running with no issues. Now I need to rewrite some images to codeigniter controller/method.

This is my .htaccess file which works fine

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|media|static|public)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Now I need something like this to rewrite images to codeigniter. **Rewrite not redirect**

```
RewriteRule ^(media/somefolder/someimage.jpg)$ /some_controller/somemethod?param=value [L]
```

I added the following line (this is not codeigniter just a regular php file) just for testing to make sure RewriteRule works and it's working fine

```
RewriteRule ^(media/somefolder/someimage.jpg)$ public/myphpfile.php?ipath=$1 [L]
```

But if I try any of the following I get codeigniter's page not found error page.

```
RewriteRule ^(media/somefolder/someimage.jpg)$ /some_controller/somemethod/?ipath=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(media/somefolder/someimage.jpg)$ index.php?c=some_controller&m=somemethod&ipath=$1 [L]
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: may I know what value do you want the `ipath` to contains?

Comment: the whole matching url in paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

#### To add exception to only a specific image

Add the `media` rule like this :

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(media/somefolder/someimage.jpg)$ /index.php?/some_controller/somemethod/?ipath=$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|media|static|public)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

---

#### To add exception to all images inside the media directory

Since you've filtered out to ignore the `media` directory on this rule :

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|media|static|public)
```

In order to rewrite the `media` path to a controller instead of ignoring it, remove the `media` rule from it :

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|static|public)
```

Add the `media` rule like this :

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
# removed the media form below rule
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|static|public)
RewriteRule ^(media/somefolder/someimage.jpg)$ /index.php?/some_controller/somemethod/?ipath=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i'm afraid this gives me 500 internal server error. Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects.